# Firebase Swift user Authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am receiving the following error when setting logging in to Firebase in my app:

> Error Domain=FirebaseAuthentication Code=-8 "(Error Code: INVALID_USER) The specified user does not exist." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=(Error Code: INVALID_USER) The specified user does not exist.}
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Code:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
  if let email = emailTextField.text where email != "", let pwd = passwordTextField.text where pwd != "" {
    DataService.ds.BASE_REF.authUser(email, password: pwd, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
      if error != nil {
        print (error)
        if error.code == NONEXISTING_USER {
          DataService.ds.BASE_REF.createUser(email, password: pwd, withValueCompletionBlock: { error, result in
            if  error.code == INVALID_EMAIL {
              self.showErrorAlert("Wrong Email", msg: "Sorry wrong email address entered")
              if error.code == -6 {
                self.showErrorAlert("Wrong Password", msg: "Enter a new password")
              }
            } else {
              NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue([KEY_UID], forKey: KEY_UID)
              DataService.ds.BASE_REF.authUser(email, password: pwd, withCompletionBlock: { err, authData in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEQ_IDEN1, sender: nil)
              })
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  } else {
    showErrorAlert("Alert!", msg: "You must enter a Username and Password")
  }
}

func showErrorAlert (title: String, msg: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the steps you took to verify that the user *does* exist. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: I found the solution. I forgot to add an else statement. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I recommend posting your solution as an answer to the question and marking it as accepted so that anyone else who comes across this will see that it's been resolved.